# Upload a image through an HTTP form, via MultipartEntity (how to change media type from application to image)

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient, image-uploading, multipartentity

Here is my code

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();           
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.hugosys.in/www.nett-torg.no/api/rpcs/uploadfiles/?");
            File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/xperia.png");
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("post_id", new StringBody("906"));
            reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("1"));
            reqEntity.addPart("files", fileBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);                                      
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);                 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            response_string =convertStreamToString(is);



            ..........
```

**method to parse response**

```
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I m getting **success** from the server, but image is not received on server ... wht i m doing wrong

Comment: and the problem is...

Comment: what error u got ???????

Comment: I m getting success from the server, but image is not received on server ... wht i m doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i think i have to work on these things

```
public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFormPart(String paramName, String value) throws Exception {
    writeParamData(paramName, value);
}

public void addFilePart(String paramName, String fileName, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

    os.write(data);

    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}   
public void finishMultipart() throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());
}
```

I have changed `Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"` to `Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n` and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

**Apply this**

private String doFileUpload() 
{

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] imagebyte = stream.toByteArray();

    System.out.println(imagebyte + "...................................");


    String urlString = "your url";

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String image_name = cal.getTime().toString();
        image_name = image_name.replace(" ", "");
        image_name = image_name.replace(":", "");
        image_name = image_name.substring(3, 14);

        //userfile
        reqEntity.addPart("featured_img", new ByteArrayBody(imagebyte,
                "Chasin_" + image_name + "_image.jpg"));




        reqEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody(title_var));
        reqEntity.addPart("description",new StringBody(description_var));
        reqEntity.addPart("category",new StringBody(cat_var));
        reqEntity.addPart("tags",new StringBody(tag));

        reqEntity.addPart("userid",new StringBody(Constants.USER_ID));


        post.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
         HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
         response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);




    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return response_str;
}
```

Comment: getting error :( Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => image.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpqKqdc7
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 310273
        )

)
true

Comment: myimage is the compressed image  from sdcard-this method is working in my curent project

Comment: i think your are asking for this...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html

Comment: Do u know these things os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
  os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
  os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
  os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
  os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
   
  os.write(data);
  
  os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

Answer (score -1):

```
File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/photo1/image2.jpg");

if (imgFile.exists()) {
    myimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    // im.setImageBitmap(myimage);
}
```

Comment: please explain why your answer works rather than just giving it.