# How to send images to server in android application

Tags: php, android, json, image

I have four images which I want to send to server through my application. Here is my code for send data to sever along with the four images but I can't understand how can I send these images of mine to server:

```
{
    String imageUrl1 = selectedImagePath1;
    aq.id(imageview1).image(imageUrl1, true, true, 200, 0);

    String imageUrl2 = selectedImagePath2;
    aq.id(imageview2).image(imageUrl2, true, true, 200, 0);

    String imageUrl3 = selectedImagePath3;
    aq.id(imageview3).image(imageUrl3, true, true, 200, 0);

    String imageUrl4 = selectedImagePath4;
    aq.id(imageview4).image(imageUrl4 ,true, true, 200, 0);

    new GetData().execute();
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String Title = title.getText().toString();
        String Description = description.getText().toString().trim();
        String PhoneNumber = phonenumber.getText().toString();
        String Email = email.getText().toString();
        String Price = price.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://tradewale.com/open/tradedata.php?home_cat=1");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(result);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            value = obj.getString("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return value;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        int val=Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (val==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(PostAddActivity.this, "Thank you For Inquiry ",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostAddActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not clear.. what is the problem? paste the error log

Comment: **Follow my answer**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933853/upload-a-image-through-an-http-form-via-multipartentity-how-to-change-media-ty/22935077#22935077

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile); 
httpPostRequest.setEntity(mpEntity);
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
```

You have to use these libs `apache-mine4j-0.6.jar` and `httpmime-4.0.1.jar` for this.

Comment: Rajesh i m getting this error socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: if you testing in the emulator m                      http://192.168.1.9/openeans try with the host ip (server ip)

Comment: or check the INternet permissions are given or not   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />